# Messaging system (inputs stored in a textfile) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to make a "Messaging" sort of system, ill give you some background details.

It will be a messaging scenario in which is between a "Landlord and a "tenant". Im currently using tkinter/python.

I want to know how i can have a input from a tenant written directly to a textfile and then saved so then the landlord can open the text file and have the text imported to the screen

This is with tkinter and python.

The code i currently have for the messaging page is:

```
def write(x):print(x)

Label(self.GenericGui, text="Messenger",font = ('TkDefaultFont',18)).pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    txt = Text(self.GenericGui)
    txt.focus()
    txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, pady=2)
    Button(self.GenericGui, text="Save",font=('TkDefaultFont',14), command=(lambda: write(txt.get('1.0', END).strip()))).place(x=100,y=400)
    #Nav Buttons
    Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'Landlord Menu',font = ('TkDefaultFont',14),command = BackToLandlord).place(x=330,y=400)
    Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'Main Menu',font = ('TkDefaultFont',14),command = BackToMain).place(x=480,y=400)
```

Not sure if this is even enough to go on, just need to know how i can do this

Any help will be gratefully appreciated! Not very experienced!

Cheers guys 
Ross

Comment: Why write your own program to write to and read from a text file? Notepad already does that just fine.

Comment: This messaging system is only a small module of a bigger system. @Kevin

Comment: what problem are you having? Do you know how to read a file? Have you read the documentation on the `Text` widget to learn how to insert data into it?